# Change URL description programmatically in list C#

Tags: list, url

I have this list with artists that I manipulate with C#.
I can get all te values of the list with this code part and change

```
SPListItem listItem = properties.ListItem;
SPWeb artistWeb = properties.Web;
string artist = listItem["Artiest"] as string;
string adres = listItem["Adres"] as string;
string postcode = listItem["Postcode"] as string;
string woonplaats = listItem["Woonplaats"] as string;
string land = listItem["Land"] as string;
string prijs = listItem["Prijs"] as string;
string rekeningnummer = listItem["Rekeningnummer"] as string;
string email = listItem["E-Mail"] as string;


string relURL = artistWeb.ServerRelativeUrl + (artistWeb.ServerRelativeUrl.EndsWith("/") ? String.Empty : "/") + artist;
relURL = relURL.Substring(1, relURL.Length - 1);
string FullURL = artistWeb.Site.MakeFullUrl(relURL);


listItem["URL"] = FullURL;
listItem.Update();
```

So I want to set the URL description just like the last part  "listItem["URL"] = FullURL;"
Is this possible?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to use SPFieldUrlValue. Here is an example:

```
string FullURL = artistWeb.Site.MakeFullUrl(relURL);
SPFieldUrlValue UrlValue = new SPFieldUrlValue();
UrlValue.Description = "Put desciption here";
UrlValue.Url = FullUrl;

listItem["URL"] = UrlValue;
listItem.Update();
```