# Change URL of a SharePoint list programmatically

Tags: development, sharepoint-server

I have created a library programmatically within a content type my URL is  :

```
/sites/test/_layouts/15/start.aspx#/**1235**/Forms/AllItems.aspx
```

I would like to update this URL and change the

```
12345
```

by something else on my C# code (a string value  that i get somewhere else).

something like :

```
 /sites/test/_layouts/15/start.aspx#/**TEST**/Forms/AllItems.aspx
```

I success to change the Title of the library easily but not the URL.

```
SPList lst = web.Lists[oldVal];
lst.Title = properties.AfterProperties["CorporateName"].ToString();
lst.Update();
```

I searched and read many way to do it within Sharepoint Designer, but I didn't find the perfect solution to do it on Visual Studio.

Answer (score 2):

You can try this to change the URL:

```
Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell –erroraction SilentlyContinue

$libOriginalUrl = "/Lists/YourLibName1";
$libNewUrl = "/YourLibName2";
$web = Get-SPWeb -Identity http://....

$lib = $web.GetList($web.Url + $libOriginalUrl)
$rootFolder = $lib.RootFolder;
$rootFolder.MoveTo($web.Url + $libNewUrl)
```

Comment: Thank u, but i would like to do it without PowerShell is it possible ?

Comment: @JeanJacques1998 To do this with Sharepoint Designer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12904944/change-sharepoint-library-url or in C# http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/59070/change-url-description-programmatically-in-list-c

Answer (score 0):

I did it on C# with this below code

```
SPList lst = web.Lists[properties.ListItem["Name"].ToString()];
SPFolder folder = web.Folders[lst.RootFolder.Url];
folder.MoveTo(properties.AfterProperties["Nickname"].ToString());
```